# InteliJ and Maven are not resolving Thymeleaf dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'am using  :: Spring Boot  (v2.0.2.RELEASE)
Java version is 1.8.0_162
While am trying to add the dependency for Thymeleaf templates in Maven inteliJ isn't resolving it, while taking some course and i do the exact same way and there is working

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

It's not resolving and not creating templates under static folder
Thank you

Comment: have you checked if Maven auto import is turned on? https://imgur.com/a/K7MNBHR

Comment: Show your `mvn clean install -X -e` log.

Answer (score 0):

In `application.properties` file of the application add:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

and in the pom.xml add dependency for nekohtml like this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.22</version>
    </dependency>
```